# Excel VBA - Code breaks when Excel opens

Tags: vba, excel

I just discover problem with my code, which not appears yesterday.
This is code from "Sheet1 (Calculator)":

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Sheets("Calculator").ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "Materials!B4:B7"
    Sheets("Calculator").ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Sheets("Calculator").Range("T18") = ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1
Select Case Sheets("Calculator").ComboBox1.ListIndex
    Case 0
        Sheets("Calculator").ComboBox2.ListFillRange = "Materials!G4:G5"
        Sheets("Calculator").ComboBox2.ListIndex = 0
    Case 1
        Sheets("Calculator").ComboBox2.ListFillRange = "Materials!G6"
        Sheets("Calculator").ComboBox2.ListIndex = 0
    Case 2
        Sheets("Calculator").ComboBox2.ListFillRange = "Materials!G7:G10"
        Sheets("Calculator").ComboBox2.ListIndex = 0
    Case 3
        Sheets("Calculator").ComboBox2.ListFillRange = "Materials!G11:G12"
        Sheets("Calculator").ComboBox2.ListIndex = 0
End Select
End Sub
```

Everything working fine, while Excel is opened. But if I save and close Excel and then reopen it, code breaks at first line under "Case 0" with error message:

```
Run-time error '438'
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

Then when I stop debuging and change item in ComboBox1, code works fine again and ComboBox2 is filled with correct data. Do you have any ideas where can be problem?

[Here is the file.](http://www.filedropper.com/snapfitcalculator)

Comment: whats the error message?

Comment: Oh, sorry, i forgot. Question is now updated with error message. If needed, I can send whole xlsm file to internet.

Comment: @SilentCry did you solve this issue somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if you initialized your ComboBox object properly.....but this should work:

```
Set ComboBox1 = Sheets("Calculator").Shapes(1)
ComboBox1.ControlFormat.ListFillRange = "Materials!B4:B7"
```

so mayb its because mainly you are missing the ControlFormat thing!?

Comment: It's not working for me... Here is file: http://www.filedropper.com/snapfitcalculator I'm really new in VBA, so I don't understand why this works when Excel is opened but not, when I'm just open Excel.

Comment: Avoid listfillrange anytime; Use .List instead: Sheets("Calculator").ComboBox1.List = sheets("Materials").Range("B4:B7").value

Comment: With Sheets("Calculator")  .ComboBox2.List = Sheets("Materials").Range("G4:G5").Value  End With   NOT WORKING.  With Sheets("Calculator")  .ComboBox2.ListFillRange = "Materials!G4:G5"  End With  WORKS.  But still not work, when excel is just opened :(   OMG, how to add newline here? Manual tells, the two spaces are needed, but it not works :(

Comment: well a bad and ugly workaround would be just to avoid the error the putting an `On Error Resume Next` at the start of  your `Private Sub ComboBox1_change()` function.  
  
    `Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()`
        `On Error Resume Next`

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  with Sheets("Calculator")
   .Range("T18") = ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1
   if .ComboBox1.ListIndex > -1 Then .ComboBox2.List=sheets("Materials").range(G4:G5").offset(choose(.ComboBox1.ListIndex+1).value
  end with
End Sub
```